# monitoring user activity in linux

Tags: linux, monitoring

I need to implement some kind of daemon that would check who logged in (with ip address) and when, what commands did that person use, and other basic stuff like differences in edited files that would help me to be sure what's going on in my system.

The log can be saved anywhere on the system (I don't need giant monitoring systems like zabbix etc.).

audit is ok, but it needs a lot of configuration, so I thought maybe there is something easier to use.

Comment: `psacct` (for CentOS/Fedora Linux / RHEL) or `acct` (for Ubuntu / Debian Linux) might be much easier and handy tool. And another one [Snoopy](https://github.com/a2o/snoopy)

Answer (score 0):

It will be not filled in the correct answer to the your question, type `last` show you to who logged in with its IP addr.